# Mercurial project overlapping?

Tags: mercurial

I have a site/backoffice solution that works with this structure:

```
/bo         // mercurial repo
/site       // site files
/www/admin  // mercurial repo
/var        // site specific vars
```

The backoffice works seamless across several sites and therefore all projects have a mercurial repo and code contributions done to project A always get replicated on projects B and C. This has worked well so far but now I feel I should also be doing a repo to the root /.

Is it possible? Can I have a repo on / excluding both the /bo and the /www/admin and have it all work nicely together or should I anticipate problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a repo at the root, and:

- declare `/site` and `/var` as [**SubRepos**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos),
- while ignoring `/bo` and `/www/admin`

That way, all your current repos still go on unchanged, but you also have one global repo with only what you need.

Comment: I've done some testing and your solution seams to work pretty well for my needs. Thank you very much for your input!